# Where is the file location for the GnuCash icon?

Tags: icons, gnucash

My Comodo virtual GnuCash shortcut doesn't use the GC icon, so I'm trying to reset it.  I have looked and looked, and I cannot find the icon file anywhere.  I looked in the folder indicated [under number 1 on this page,](https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Desktop_Shortcuts) but the folder is empty.  I'm searching all file types, not just icon/png files.  I've looked through every file in the GnuCash directory, and even did an indexed search for gnucash-icon, but no dice. Mod, if this is a bad question or should be on a different board, my apologies.
Many thanks!

Comment: Does Comodo is Ubuntu? Which exact version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like most icon files that aren't tied to an icon theme they are in some subfolders of `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/`:

```
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/gnucash-icon.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/gnucash-icon.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/apps/gnucash-icon.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/gnucash-icon.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/gnucash-icon.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/gnucash-icon.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/gnucash-icon.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps/gnucash-icon.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/96x96/apps/gnucash-icon.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/gnucash-icon.svg
```

And pixmaps:

```
/usr/share/gnucash/pixmaps/gnucash-icon-128x128.png
/usr/share/gnucash/pixmaps/gnucash-icon-16x16.png
/usr/share/gnucash/pixmaps/gnucash-icon-256x256.png
/usr/share/gnucash/pixmaps/gnucash-icon-32x32.png
/usr/share/gnucash/pixmaps/gnucash-icon-48x48.bmp
/usr/share/gnucash/pixmaps/gnucash-icon-48x48.png
/usr/share/gnucash/pixmaps/gnucash-icon-64x64.png
/usr/share/gnucash/pixmaps/gnucash-icon-96x96.png
/usr/share/gnucash/pixmaps/gnucash-icon.ico
/usr/share/pixmaps/gnucash-icon-32x32.xpm
```